# Google Apps - Sheets - Column for Modified By

Tags: google-sheets

I'm needing a column on a Google Sheet that contains Modified By information. I will be sharing this sheet with other users in our Google Apps domain. Here is the script I currently have:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var actUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var dateCol = actSht.getLastColumn();
    var lastCell = actSht.getRange(index,dateCol);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");

    lastCell.setValue("Modified By: " + actUser + " - " + date);
}
```

That returns "Modified By:  at 12/15/2014 12:33" in the last column. This applies to myself (the creator of the document) as well as another test user I shared the sheet with. Any suggestions?

Comment: The docs says that the email is not available under some circumstances: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user

Comment: It wasn't even asking to authorize. Turns out the OnEdit event can't pull that info. I had to create a custom function and define an On Edit trigger for that function. Then everything started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the OnEdit function can't pull user info. I created a custom function instead of OnEdit() and then set an On Edit trigger that pointed to that function. Then everything worked as expected.